# Show JS errors in iframe during qunit testing within phantomjs

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, qunit, phantomjs, gruntjs

I am developing a cross-domain RPC library for which I want to do some unit-testing using qunit.

In order to do the testing properly I've setup a grunt file that launches a node.js server and phantomjs to load the test `rpc.html` as described [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/docs/task_qunit.md) (using a server task so that different domains can be simulated, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1`). This test opens an iframe with `frame.html` that mocks the RPC commands which are asserted within `rpc.html`.

So far all good. The problem I am encountering is that whenever a JS error occurs within `frame.html` it is not outputted to the console. Only errors that happen in `rpc.html` are shown. Although outputs of `console.log()` etc are working in `frame.html`.

Is there a way I can get all JavaScript errors to be shown that occur in `frame.html`, including parse errors and such?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have `onError` handlers (PhantomJS, frame.hmtl)?

Comment: @Stan hmm yeah that does actually work - even on syntax errors :O. Combining it with `console.error()` it solves my problem. Thanks a lot - I think you should post it as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhantomJS supports `onError` event handlers in its `page` objects, so that information about JavaScript exceptions can be intercepted and handled as appropriate.

AFAIK, you should possibly also check if loaded web-pages do not have their own `window.onerror`, because if they return true, the errors will be treated as handled.